# List<CustomObject>: How Custom Object removes itself from the list?

Tags: c#, generic-list

I created a class that implements a `System.Timers.Timer` with an elapse event.

```
private void ElapseEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e){
//read from serial port device
}
```

In the main program I have a `private List<MyTimerClass> _timers`.

I dynamically start the timer and add it to the timer list.

```
 var timer1= new MyTimerClass();
 timer1.Execute("Device A");
_timers.Add(timer1);

 var timer2= new MyTimerClass();
 timer2.Execute("Device B");
_timers.Add(timer2);
```

When the `ElapseEvent` encounters an error and the serial port was disconnected, I want to remove the timer from the List. How can I possibly do that?

Comment: Generally speaking, all event handlers in the framework has the `source` parameter.  The `source` will usually refer to the object to which the event was registered (in your case, the individual timer that has elapsed).  You should be able to just cast the `source` to an instance of a `MyTimerClass` and remove that from your list.  That is, assuming you followed the patterns in the framework in your class.  We can't say for sure until we see how you implemented it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a OnError Method at the class that contains the timers. In order to let the parent class know that an error occurs. Something like the following:

At MyTimerClass

```
public MyTimerClass(Action<MyTimerClass, Exception> onError)
{
    this.onError = onError;
}

private void ElapseEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e){
try{
//read from serial port device
}
catch(Exception ex) // It would be better if you know the exceptions you want to handle
{
  if(this.onError != null)
  {
   this.onError(this, ex);
  }
}
}
```

At the parent class:

```
var timer1= new MyTimerClass(this.OnTimerError);
 timer1.Execute("Device A");
_timers.Add(timer1);

 var timer2= new MyTimerClass(this.OnTimerError);
 timer2.Execute("Device B");
_timers.Add(timer2);



public void OnTimerError(MyTimerClass timer, Exception error)
{
 //Log the exception
  _timers.Remove(timer);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If your _timers is a static variable, then create a static event handler in the same class. When the error is thrown in a timer's `ElapseEvent`, call the event handler with reference to itself, and have the static event handler remove the error'ed timer from the list.

Answer (score 1):

The [Observer Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern).  .NET has [native support for this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd990377.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You should check out the [Command Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern); sounds like it would be perfect for you.